# Constraints and keys in sqlite database model

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I'm setting up a simple Sqlite database using the modelling tool in Navicat. The setup is as follows:

```
Table 1: _employer_ 
col1: name (PK)
-----------
Mcdonalds  | 
NHS London |
Police     |
-----------


Table 2: _jobs_
col1: job_title
col2: emp_name (FK - referencing _employer_.name)
col3: job_id (PK - automatically generated)
----------------------------
Mcdonalds  | Cleaner  | 345 |
McDonalds  | Kitchens | 782 |
Police     | Kitchens | 999 |
NHS London | Nurse    | 123 |
NHS London | Doctor   | 126 | 
NHS London | Cleaner  | 112 |  
----------------------------
```

The final constraint I wish to add is that the combination of (`emp_name` and `job_title`
) in the `_jobs_` table is unique, so that, for example, you couldn't have two `NHS London | cleaner` entries. When I add this constraint however Navicat complains that *the cardinality is not possible to be realized with the current constraints*. What is the problem with this set-up?. In case it helps, here is the SQL schema generated by this model:

```
CREATE TABLE "_employer_" (
"name" TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("name") 
);

CREATE TABLE "_jobs_" (
"job_title" TEXT NOT NULL,
"emp_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
"job_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("job_id") ,
CONSTRAINT "fk__jobs___employer__1" FOREIGN KEY ("emp_name") REFERENCES "_employer_" ("name"),
CONSTRAINT "constrain_job" UNIQUE ("emp_name", "job_title")
);
```

Perhaps the problem boils down to using a `foreign key` (which is a `primary key` in its own table) as part of a `combination unique key`. In my example `_employer_.name` is the `primary key` in the `_employer_` table, a reference for a `Foreign Key` in the `_jobs_` table (`_jobs_.emp_name`), and finally this `emps_name` field is part of a combination `unique key` in the the `_jobs_` table. Theoretically, is there any problem with doing this?

Comment: Error: unknown column "organisation" in foreign key definition

Comment: Works fine for me in version 3.7.9, after deleting the broken foreign key reference.

Comment: Sorry, mistakes in original schema. Have corrected. Still getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

Both your schemas (before editing and after editing) build without error for me on SQLite 3.7.9 and 3.7.16.2. After `pragma foreign_keys=on;`, foreign key constraints work as designed.

If I were in your shoes, I'd test by using the SQLite command line instead of Navicat. I don't see a SQLite problem here.